# Sort files and folders together by name (not by type)?

Tags: windows-explorer

In windows explorer i don't know how can i sort files and folders by name one after the other. For example i have this list in a folder (order is false, only example):

```
alfa [folder]
anto.rar
beta [folder]
gamma [folder]
gin.zip
```

and i try to sort by name - explorer gives me back as a result:

```
alfa [folder]
beta [folder]
gamma [folder]
anto.rar
gin.zip
```

But i want this order

```
alfa [folder]
anto.rar
beta [folder]
gamma [folder]
gin.zip
```

I want a solution that will give me then the ability to select multiple files as described in this post: [How can I activate or deactivate the CTRL at all times?](https://superuser.com/questions/774102/how-can-i-activate-or-disactivate-ctrl-always)

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show Files and Folders Sorted by name NOT Folders First then Files](http://superuser.com/questions/416059/show-files-and-folders-sorted-by-name-not-folders-first-then-files), [Windows 7 - Windows Explorer sorts files and folders separately](http://superuser.com/questions/204016/windows-7-windows-explorer-sorts-files-and-folders-separately?rq=1)

Comment: you're right user332153.

Comment: CMD will give you the order you want: `dir /on`

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to do this in Windows Explorer.

Closest way would be to use:  **View | Group by | Name**